# Gridview databind messing up post backs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a page which sends emails that contains drop down lists as well as a gridview.

I am having an issue with the page posting back on ddlselectedindexchanged and the gridview posting back oncheckchangedas the callbacks do not work.

if i comment out the gridview.databind the callbacks all work.

```
     <tr>
                                                        <td class="rightalignment">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFacility" runat="server" Text="Facility:"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFacility" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                            AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
this is the gridview:
<asp:GridView ID="GvEmail" runat="server" CssClass="tabulardata" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                                            AllowPaging="false" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="false" PageSize="100" Width="100%" >
                                                            <Columns>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" ShowHeader="False">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkselect_change"
                                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name"
                                                                    ItemStyle-Width="12%" NullDisplayText="N/A" />
                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"
                                                                    ItemStyle-Width="12%" NullDisplayText="N/A" />

                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmailAddress") %>'>
                                                                        </asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            </Columns>
                                                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                <table id="tblRequest" border="1" cellspacing="0" class="tabulardata" rules="all"
                                                                    style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                                            Last Name
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                                            First Name
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                                            Email Address
                                                                        </th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" colspan="4">
                                                                            <strong>No Record Found</strong>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                        </asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIUtility.HideMessage(this.Page);
        try
        {


     if (!Page.IsPostBac

k)
            {
                this.GetFacilities(0);


this.GvEmail.DataBind();
        this.GetCorporate();
        this.GetInternalContacts();
        this.GetEmailFrom();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
        UIUtility.ShowMessage(ex.Message, true, this.Page);
    }

}


    private void GetEmailAddress()
        {
            try
            {
                FacilityBLL = new FacilityBll();
                this.GvEmail.DataSource = FacilityBLL.GetEmailAddressPerCorporateFacility(this.ddlCorporate.SelectedValue, this.ddlFacility.SelectedValue);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UIUtility.ShowMessage(ex.Message, true, this.Page);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you get an error, if so, please post.

Comment: no i did not. the onselectedindexchanged breakpoints  just do not get hit

Answer (score 0):

it was in an update panel.

Upon commenting out the update panel i recieved an error that  maxhttpkeys was maxed out.
I added to the web.config 
and the error was solved and the call backs worked